# How do I store largest double value possible (1.8e+308) in a variable, in binary form?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

In Java, since double has a width of 64 bits, I tried storing largest double value possible in a variable named "a", in binary form, as shown below:

```
double a = 0B111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111;
```

Why is it giving me a compile time error as I have only used 63 bits (which within the allowed range)?

Comment: Why not just use the existing constant: java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I could, but I am just curious. Why is it restricting me from using all 64 bits?

Answer (score 2):

`0B111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111` is an int literal, not double. Since it is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it doesn't compile.

If you want to get a double value from its binary representation, you should use `Double.longBitsToDouble` (and use a long literal instead of int):

```
double a = Double.longBitsToDouble(0B111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111L);
```

Comment: Or I could just use a "l" or "L" as a suffix, right?

Comment: @SakshamTiwari Yes, and `Double.longBitsToDouble` is also necessary. Otherwise, you will get `Long.MAX_VALUE` instead of `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

The largest double is not all bits '1', the format is the IEEE754. You can play around with a converter to see the effect of the individual bits:
http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html

The maximum number you can represent with float or double is infinite. You can try this:

```js
double my_max_double = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

Comment: First point, the largest value of a double is 63 times 1 (Since the very first bit is a sign bit). Second point, if we are only allowed 64 bits to represent a double value in binary form, how is it possible to assign it an infinite value?

Comment: You have a sign, an exponent and a mantissa. Exponent has special codes that means zero, infinite and other special conditions that are handled by the FPU.

Comment: @SakshamTiwari You are probably confusing `long` numbers and `double` numbers. `long` numbers are integer numbers with double precision. `double` numbers are [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) numbers with double precision.

Comment: Oh okay, got it!